# AWS Lambda package target error when including .net standard library

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, .net-standard

I'm trying to package a .net core lambda function which includes a reference to a .net standard 2.0 class library.

Publishing and running locally using the AWS Lambda toolkit works fine. However when I try to deploy to AWS, the packaging is failing with the below error.

I tried targeting my lambda function for both .net core 2.1 and 3.1 but with the same results.

Any ideas please?

```
$ dotnet lambda package
Amazon Lambda Tools for .NET Core applications (3.3.1)
Project Home: https://github.com/aws/aws-extensions-for-dotnet-cli, https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet

Executing publish command
Deleted previous publish folder
... invoking 'dotnet publish', working folder 'C:\Users\andre\source\repos\awslambda3\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\publish'
... Disabling compilation context to reduce package size. If compilation context is needed pass in the "/p:PreserveCompilationContext=false" switch.
... publish: Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.4.0+e901037fe for .NET Core
... publish: Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
... publish:   Restore completed in 53.2 ms for C:\Users\andre\source\repos\LambdaModels\LambdaModels.csproj.
... publish:   Restore completed in 572.08 ms for C:\Users\andre\source\repos\awslambda3\AWSLambda3.csproj.
... publish:   Restore completed in 573 ms for C:\Users\andre\source\repos\AWSLambda3.Tests\AWSLambda3.Tests.csproj.
... publish: C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error NETSDK1005: Assets file 'C:\Users\andre\source\repos\LambdaModels\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'netcoreapp2.1' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. [C:\Users\andre\source\repos\LambdaModels\LambdaModels.csproj]
... publish:   LambdaModels -> C:\Users\andre\source\repos\LambdaModels\bin\Release\netstandard2.0\LambdaModels.dll
... publish:   AWSLambda3 -> C:\Users\andre\source\repos\AWSLambda3\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\AWSLambda3.dll
... publish:   AWSLambda3.Tests -> C:\Users\andre\source\repos\AWSLambda3.Tests\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\rhel.7.2-x64\AWSLambda3.Tests.dll
... publish:   AWSLambda3.Tests -> C:\Users\andre\source\repos\awslambda3\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\publish\
... publish:   AWSLambda3 -> C:\Users\andre\source\repos\awslambda3\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\rhel.7.2-x64\AWSLambda3.dll
... publish:   AWSLambda3 -> C:\Users\andre\source\repos\awslambda3\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\publish\
Failed to create application package
```

Comment: This is your actual error: `project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'`

Comment: What is the solution for it? The only solution I found is that I would have to add netcoreapp in the targetframeworks element of the .net standard csproj. But I don't believe this is appropriate. When you use the .net standard class library with a .net core console or some other project type you don't have to do that. Besides when you don't have the source for the .net standard it would not be possible recompiling targeting .netcoreapp. I'm after a solution that would only affect the lambda function project which I have control on, and not the referenced projects. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this issue by removing `aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json` file

Comment: @Andre I'm deploying lambda using CDK with resources specified their, so this file wasn't needed for me. If your app relies on this file, then try changing .net core version to 3.1 in it